# Is it possible in Netbeans to synchronize with CVS a fully remote c/c++ project

Tags: netbeans, configuration

With Netbeans 8.2 WITH the CVS plugin installed.

I have managed to configure a remote C/C++ project and it is fine. I can compile and get compilation error.

But the project is hosted on a CVS repo, and I have no option about CVS for the remote project.

I can see that there is a menu entry for GIT, but nothing for CVS.

However if I checkout locally the file and create a local project, then I have the CVS support in the IDE.

Is it possible to have CVS for a remote C/C++ project ?

Comment: Not related to any of the two **distinct** programming languages C or C++.

Comment: Well, this is related to the configuration of a remote c/c++ project, which is quite different than configuring a Java project.

Comment: What is a "C/C++" project? I'm still to see the specification of that language. For C: please provide a reference to where the standard mentions netbeans or project setup in general and I will add the tag myself. Until then: this is not related to the C **language** (nor C++).

Comment: Do you have better suggestion than c / c++ tags for a question that is 100% related to the configuration of a C project ?